# How are "xterm" and "screen" related?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, xterm

I am not quite sure if there is any subtle or wide differences between screen and xterm. I have used screen before and had it being described as kind of like a multiplexer and have tried xterm a few times. Can anyone explain the differences between the two as well as the pros and cons to them both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you don't see [actual terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) all that often anymore, but for instance the Linux text consoles on (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +) <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> are considered terminals.

xterm is a *terminal emulator* for systems running the x-window system and a graphical user interface. It provides only a single terminal, typically running a single process (an interactive shell by default). `Konsole` and similarly `Gnome Terminal` are slightly more advanced terminal emulators for the GUI.

You run `screen` from within a terminal or a terminal emulator like xterm or PuTTY. In that single terminal window screen functions like a window manager to run multiple virtual terminals.

Answer (score 7):

*From the perspective of **what's similar** between* `xterm` *and* `screen`:

Both are **emulations** of the real **hardware device** "terminal", like this VT100:

[image: vt100]

<sub>[VT100 - Wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DEC_VT100_terminal.jpg)</sub>

- `xterm` emulates **one terminal** showing it as a GUI **window** on screen
- `screen` emulates **multiple terminals**, but does not actually emulate the output part - it behaves like a program that itself **needs a terminal** to show on - but **only one**!

They solve **different**, but **related** problems - and can be combined to solve more complex use cases:

For example, we can run two programs that each need a terminal,
and make `screen` pretend to them they each get a terminal,
while screen only needs one.
And then we can - instead of really using a terminal -
use `xterm` to emulate a terminal, showing the output of `screen`,
which shows the output of the two programs.

Note that there are some terminal emulators like [`terminator`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/terminator.1.html), that implement the features of `xterm` and `screen` **at the same time** - which would of course be totally confusing when used as base to answer this question. Many more terminal emulators support multiple terrminals as tabs in one window, including the common [`gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) and `konsole`

Answer (score 6):

They are fundamentally different.
I think the main difference is: 
Screen allows you to detach the session and reattach it later from a different place.

For example you might have some important process running in your xterm but unfortunately your monitor breaks and you can no longer use your computer.

If the process runs in `screen` you could now 'ssh` into your machine, detach the "screen" from the unusable xterm and reatach it to your ssh connection.

Another scenario is a process running on a remote machine. Without screen it is difficult to resume the process if you need to disconnect your ssh connection, with screen it is easy.